# Cant access Auth status in Model

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am trying to access my auth status in on a Model, i used an eloquent mutator to add a field to my model.

```
//use Illunimate\Facades\Support\Auth;
protected $appends = ['value'];

public function getValueAttribute(){ return Auth::user()->id()}
```

That is the code,
but its returning false even when logged in

Comment: if the answer is useful to you. you should add it as best answer and give it a point. last time you did not response either.

Comment: You can access the users Id like Auth::id().

Answer (score 0):

You write the code in the wrong way. you miss the user() and then you use parentheses after id your code must be like this:

```
public function getValueAttribute(){ return Auth::user()->id;}
```

Comment: Yeah that was my bad, But that actually seemed not to be the problem, The problem is any time i try to call the auth facade or helper method in the ##getValueAttribute method it returns null

Comment: @Maxwell did you try to include it the Auth facade?

Comment: Yes i even tried using dependency injection it still returns null

Comment: @Maxwell I miss the ; . it should access it. try to save it in a variable and then return the variable

Answer (score 0):

```
Corrected version of your code
public function getValueAttribute(){ return Auth::user()->id}

from your view you could check first to avoid crashes :
if (Auth::check()) {
    // The user is logged in...
 {{Auth::user()->id}}
}else{
 // The user is NOT logged in...
}
```

Comment: do you have it on git? i could check it out and paste the solution here!

Comment: You don't also need to return "Auth::user()->id" from a function, its already available to you anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems correct except its missing `;`
So try this

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

public function getValueAttribute(){ return Auth::user()->id();}
```

If that doesn't work try this also`php artisan make:auth` and then `php artisan migrate`
This will reset auth and migratation .
Hope this helps